# Device status unknown in the cacti application

Tags: cacti

I am trying to plot the graphs in cacti, but I am getting status as 'unknown' under device section , I dont know how to even debug this.What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

see

http://docs.cacti.net/faq

Status Unknown
If the status of your device remains 'Unknown', ensure that you have added graphs to that device.
If there are no graphs, Cacti will not poll the device, and the status will remain 'Unknown'.

make sure you add cron with the following command.

php cacti/poller.php

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Mistake I was doing was-
While creating Graphs, I selected the interface and clicked on create graph directly without noticing option " Select a  graph type".

Here you need to select "In/Out Bits" before clicking on create.

The new version of cacti is showing "Cisco LRE Stats" as the default option which is creating all this mess.

True - If there are no graphs, Cacti will not poll the device.